# jdialog box opens but appear to be blank

Tags: java, swing, jdialog

I have written the following code to generate please wait `JDialog` while generation of decision tree but it opens up and appears to be blank

```
public JDialog pleasewait()
{
    JDialog dialog = new JDialog();
    JLabel label = new JLabel("Please wait...");
    label.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/decision_tree_runner/load.gif"))); // NOI18N
    dialog.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    dialog.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    dialog.setTitle("Please Wait...");
    dialog.add(label);
    dialog.pack();

    return dialog;

}

private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    JDialog dialog = pleasewait();
    dialog.repaint();
    dialog.setVisible(true);
    FypProject fyp_project = new FypProject();
    try {fyp_project.main_fypproject();} catch (SQLException ex) {}
    dialog.setVisible(false);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is likely that  `fyp_project.main_fypproject()` is a long running/blocking call, which when called from within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread, will stop it from been able to process new events, including the repaint request.

Consider using something like a `SwingWorker`, opening the dialog first, execute the worker and when it's `done` method is called, close the dialog

Take a look at [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) and [Worker Threads and SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) for more details

Answer (score 0):

I think it has to do with where in the dialog the JLabel gets added. The lack of our layout manager makes this difficult.

Try adding this before you add the JLabel:

`dialog.setLayout(new GridLayout());`

and remove:

`dialog.pack();`

Comment: adding this has shrinked the dialog box and has not shown anything still

Comment: What happens if you remove the image from the label?

Comment: user489041 still same no changes

Comment: There is already a layout manager in use, so changing it should have no effect...and removing pack is a very bad idea

Answer (score 0):

i did the following steps

1. created separate form for pleasewait
2. created thread for fyp_project.main_fypproject()
3. passed object of form to thread class
4. in run method setvisible() option of pleasewait to false

   ```
   public class thread_for_pleasewait implements Runnable{
   Thread t ;
   please_wait_form pwf;   
   decision_tree dt;
   FypProject fyp_project = new FypProject();
    @Override

    public void run()
   {
   String[] args = null;
    try {
       fyp_project.main_fypproject();
       pwf.setVisible(false);
       dt.setVisible(true);
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
       Logger.getLogger(thread_for_pleasewait.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
   }
     public void start(please_wait_form pwf,decision_tree dt)
     {
      t = new Thread(this);
      t.start();
      this.pwf=pwf;
      this.dt=dt;
     }  
   }
   ```